# Eigenvalue distribution of a random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Is there any closed form distribution formula for the distribution of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{X}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{X}$ where the entries of $\mathbf{X}$ are independent Gaussian random variables with different variances $\sigma_{ij}^2$. Moreover, in the diagonal factorization $\mathbf{X}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{U}^{\mathrm{H}}$, the unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$ has Haar distribution? Is it independent of $\mathbf{\Lambda}$?

Comment: no, $U$ is not uniformly distributed in the unitary group (no Haar distribution) and eigenvectors and eigenvalues are not independent. There is not much more to say in this completely general case.

Comment: Is there any result for non-identical cases?

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment to indicate how hopeless this is: Consider the edge case of $\sigma_{ij} = \lambda_i \delta_{ij}.$ The unitary matrix then is the identity matrix, so is quite far from Haar distributed. The eigenvalues are distributed normally with the covariance matrix $\mathbf{X},$ also quite far from the "standard" case. An interesting question is whether there is a less trivial case when there is a discrete set of $\mathbf{U}.$

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** *"Is there any result for non-identical cases?"*

The eigenvalue distribution function is known if $\sigma^2_{ij}=w_i$ depends only on the row index, see for example [arXiv:1310.2467](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2467)

$$P(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)\propto\prod_{i<j}|x_i-x_j|^\beta\prod_k x_k^{1-2/\beta}\int dU \exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\beta\,{\rm tr}\,UXX^H U^{\rm H}W^{-1}\right),$$
where $W={\rm diag}\,(w_1,w_2,\ldots w_n)$ and $\beta=1$ for real matrix elements, $\beta=2$ for complex matrix elements.

The measure $dU$ is the Haar measure in ${\rm O}(n)$ for $\beta=1$ and in ${\rm U}(n)$ for $\beta=2$. This is the socalled [Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/), which has a closed-form expression for $\beta=2$ (it’s a ratio of determinants). Note that the integral depends only on the eigenvalues $x_i$ of $XX^H$. For $W$ proportional to the identity matrix we recover the usual [Wishart distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Probability_density_function)